# Meaning of: "Therefore whether it were I or they" in scripture

Tags: meaning, expressions

In the following passage:

> Moreover, brethren, I declare unto you the gospel which I preached unto you, which also ye have received, and wherein ye stand; by which also ye are saved, if ye keep in memory what I preached unto you, unless ye have believed in vain. For I delivered unto you first of all that which I also received, how that Christ died for our sins according to the scriptures; and that he was buried, and that he rose again the third day according to the scriptures: and that he was seen of Cephas, then of the twelve: after that, he was seen of above five hundred brethren at once; of whom the greater part remain unto this present, but some are fallen asleep. After that, he was seen of James; then of all the apostles. And last of all he was seen of me also, as of one born out of due time. For I am the least of the apostles, that am not meet to be called an apostle, because I persecuted the church of God. But by the grace of God I am what I am: and his grace which was bestowed upon me was not in vain; but I laboured more abundantly than they all: yet not I, but the grace of God which was with me. Therefore whether it were I or they, so we preach, and so ye believed.
>
> [1 Corinthians 15:1–11 (AKJV)](http://biblehub.com/kjv/1_corinthians/15.htm)

What does the passage: *Therefore whether it were I or they* mean? Does it concern the personal vs the other or does it prophecy all are brothers and sisters and that lineage is an anachronism, or is it something more profound?

Comment: From a cursory glance, it's likely the same *they* in *I laboured more abundantly than they all*. The *so we preach* is also consistent: *I* + *they* = *we*. For a more convincing answer, consider which sentences or notions the word *Therefore* ties together - that would give you the context to identify *they*.

Comment: Are you suggesting there are still those who do not understand the workings of Karma, who still think that though they gain temporary reprieve when doing certain ill-works in the name of the greater whole, that they are still wedded to those ill works in and of themselves, and have not been able to progress due to circumstance. Is that the meaning of the scriptural passage?

Comment: The passage has nothing to do with the notion of karma. Instead, the passage says that *Christ died for our sins according to the scriptures ...*, and that's what Paul and the others preached, and what the people he was writing to believed.

Comment: Why use this version when there are more accessible ones? [TLB](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1+Corinthians+15&version=TLB) has '10 But whatever I am now it is all because God poured out such kindness and grace upon me—and not without results: for I have worked harder than all the other apostles, yet actually I wasn’t doing it, but God working in me, to bless me. 11 It makes no difference who worked the hardest, I or they; the important thing is that we preached the Gospel to you and you believed it.' If you want to claim authority-of-first-version, that would be Greek.

Comment: PS: Don't call me a moron. The King James Version is the Authorised Version, but it's called one or the other, never "Authorised King James Version". You seem to have forgotten the [Be nice policy](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice), which is Not A Good Thing To Do.

Comment: Bible Gateway has two versions, one Authorised and one not.

Comment: Oh. It's American. It does say "Authorised (King James) Version" with brackets spelling out what "Authorised" actually means, but the abbreviation should really be AV, not AKJV. Anyway, that wasn't really the point of that comment.

Answer (score 6):

The *they* in that sentence is *the apostles,* who are mentioned previously. The referent for a personal pronoun will almost always be the nearest prior mention which matches for number and gender. In this case, that produces a consistent reading of the text.

> For I am the least of **the apostles,** that am not meet to be called an apostle, because I persecuted the church of God. But by the grace of God I am what I am: and his grace which was bestowed upon me was not in vain; but I laboured **more abundantly than they all:** yet not I, but the grace of God which was with me. Therefore whether it were I **or they,** so we preach, and so ye believed.

"Therefore, whether it is I who tell you, or they (the apostles) who do so, this is what we all preach, and what you have believed."